# Why is my player's movement speed changing? (using Fishnet with Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm fairly new to Unity, and I've begun learning how to use Fishnet networking. I've created a basic player movement script that syncs player position far faster than a Network Transform would. But I'm running into a bizarre problem I don't know how to solve.

In my scene, I have a Network Manager which, upon connection, spawns my Player prefab--a simple sprite with a player script and a network object. I haven't added a network transform, since I'll be syncing each player's position manually to reduce delay between clients. Here's the player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using FishNet.Object;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsOwner) //only the client that owns this object will run this code
        {
            //get input, send it to server
            float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            RpcMoveCharacter(horizontalInput, verticalInput);
        }

        //since this is an observers rpc, only the server will call it
        RpcSendCharacterPosition(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    public void RpcMoveCharacter(float x, float y)
    {
        //change the position of the server's instance of the player
        transform.Translate(x * 10f * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.right);
        transform.Translate(y * 10f * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.up);
    }

    [ObserversRpc]
    public void RpcSendCharacterPosition(float x, float y)
    {
        if (IsClientOnly)
        {
            //ensure clients' instance of the player match the server's' position
            transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

The script works perfectly...except for one problem: the movement speed of the player isn't consistent for both players. The issues only occur when I build and run my game, then have the two versions of the game connect.

When either player is a host (server + client) their player object moves at medium speed on both screens. This is the intended speed.

When the *version of my game running from my unity editor window* is only a client, the player moves at fast speed on both screen--many times faster than intended.

When the *version of my game I created using 'build and run'* is only a client, the player moves at slow speed on both screens--many times slower than intended.

I've tested everything I can think of. One test I did was to prevent the network manager from spawning the player prefab, place the player object in scene ahead of time, and convert this:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsOwner)
        {
            float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            RpcMoveCharacter(horizontalInput, verticalInput);
        }

        RpcSendCharacterPosition(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    [ServerRpc]
```

to this:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        //now anyone can control the player object
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        RpcMoveCharacter(horizontalInput, verticalInput);

        RpcSendCharacterPosition(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    }
    //same effect as note above
    [ServerRpc (RequireOwnership = false)]
```

in order to see if there was something about the player spawning feature was bugged. My changes had zero effect whatsoever--nothing changed at all. **If my *editor* was a client only it still moved the player too quickly, and if my *build* was a client only it still moved the player too slowly.**

Another thing I tried was  to make a brand new project in case I had toggled a setting weirdly or something in the last one. Once I had created a new project, all I did was import fishnet, add fishnet's default NetworkManager object to my scene, create a simple prefab called player, add a network object and the original player script to the player prefab, set the network manager to spawn the player prefab, and tried again. No luck--everything was exactly the same.

Any ideas? I'm super stuck here--I don't know what else to try, since everything in the code/scene seems to be working perfectly. I can't figure out why my build would be behaving differently than my editor's play mode, regardless of which is the server (or host) and which is the client only.

Thanks!

Comment: in general note that you sum up the vertical and horizontal movement -> you will move faster when moving diagonal (use `Vector3.ClampMaginutde` to avoid this)

Comment: And in general it is not a good idea ever to call networked methods **every frame** you can not guarantee that they arrive at the server in the same intervals since all devices have different frames per second => so `Time.deltaTime` will be invalid on the server side since one player migh still be calling this more often than the other. You should rather call it in certain intervals and make sure the server correctly compensates this fixed time interval (e.g. store last received time stamp for each player and multiply by the difference) or calculate it client side and send the final movement

Comment: I'd love to calculate it client side and send the final movement, but I have no idea how to that. I've experimented with transform.Translate and transform.position a ton to no avail--how would I do this? Should I use the horizontalInput and verticalInput variables to determine x and y variables (which I can then pass along to the server)? How do I do that? And how can I send the final movement without using update to send an rpc every frame? I can't find any guides on this (except for a few ten year old forum posts that use an oudated networking system)

Comment: `var movement = transform.rotation * Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")), 1f) * 10f * speed * Time.deltaTime;` this you do on client side and then later you use this as in `transform.position += movement;` Or calculate the position on each client and only rather sync the final position (that's what I would prefer)

Comment: Got it! That's very similar to what I was trying to do, I was just missing something basic, thanks! Once again though, what's the best way to sync the final position without using an update method? (as far as I know, SyncVars only communicate servers>clients, unless I'm missing something. Which means I need an rpc, and if I'm to use a ServerRpc, where should I call it if not in an update function?
Tysm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't really know how exactly this `Fishnet` works.

But as said in general in any networking you can never rely on

- All your devices running at the same FPS (frames per second)
- Your networked messages arriving at the server/other clients immediately
- Your networked messages arriving at the server/other clients in the exact same intervals as you ended them

So what I would rather do as mentioned is

- First of all do not send network messages every frame but rather some fixed time intervals (like e.g. often used every 0.2 seconds)
- Rather handle all local movement locally and immediately

  It would be very bad for the UX if you send your user inputs to the server and have to wait until it is applied by receiving back the resulting position. This causes a 2-times network delay which would be extremely uncanny for the local user.
- Instead of the delta rather synchronize the resulting position value.

  This way you can be sure all players are in sync with the actual resulting positions and it works immediately also for players who joined the session later or potentially missed a few input messages due to network lag.

So I would do something like

```
public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    // Interval in seconds how often to send your position to the server/clients
    [SerializeField] private float sendInterval = 0.2f;
    
    // How fast you can move in units per second
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 10f;

    // Use this to adjust your input sensitivities 
    [SerializeField] [Min(0)] private float inputSensitivityX = 1f;
    [SerializeField] [Min(0)] private float inputSensitivityY = 1f;

    // Might have to play a bit with this value to make smooth interpolation faster or slower
    // 5 is an arbitrary value but works quite good from experience
    // depends on your sendInterval and movespeed as well
    [SerializeField] privte float interpolation = 5f;

    // keeps track of passed time
    private float sendTimer;

    private Vector2 receivedTargetPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(!IsOwner)
        {
            receivedTargetPosition = transform.position;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //only the client that owns this object will run this code
        if (IsOwner) 
        {
            //get input
            var horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            var verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            var input = new Vector2(horizontalInput * inputSensitivityX, verticalInput * inputSensitivityY);
            // Makes sure that you always have maximum 1 magnitude for the input
            input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(input, 1f);

            // use the rotation to already rotate this vector from local into world space
            input = trasform.rotation * input;

            // Here you want the deltaTime of THIS DEVICE
            var movement = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * input;

            // Move your player LOCALLY
            transform.position += (Vector3)movement;
        }
        // If you are not the owner you rather apply the received position
        else
        {
            // I would e.g. smoothly interpolate somewhat like
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, receivedTargetPosition, interpolation * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Check if next send time interval has passed
        sendTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(sendTimer >= sendInterval)
        {
            sendTimer = 0;

            if(IsServer)
            {
                RpcSendPositionToClients(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            }
            else
            {
                RpcSendPositionToServer(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            }
        } 
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    public void RpcSendPositionToServer(float x, float y)
    {
        // just in case
        // the owner already gets its position in Update so nothing to do
        if(IsOwner) return;

        //change the position of the server's instance of the player
        receivedTargetPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcSendPositionToClients(float x, float y)
    {
        // Owner and server already know the positions
        if(IsOwner || IsServer) return;
        
        receivedTargetPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: @azeTrom updated the code ;) this should do it now

Comment: it works great now, thanks!! ...except that there's a pretty big delay between the two clients. Of course, if I remove the code relating to Lerping and SendIntervals, the delay disappears--but as you mentioned, that's not ideal... Any suggestions for reducing that delay without calling rpcs on every frame?

Comment: @azeTrom General idea that would solve this is to calculate the position on both, the client and the server and just correct it on that side that does not have the authority. If you want to have the authority on the client, send both: Velocity (for calculating on the server as well) and position (to correct the last calculated state/as starting point for further calculation). This way even if no position correction (and possibly no velocity) is send to the server for a while, the server can still interpolate by itself and just correct at the next message.

Comment: @azeTrom But I instead want to suggest to do it slightly different and not give the client the authority over the position. Instead it should only have the authority over the inputs: The client still calculates velocities and positions but gets corrected by server. To make this possible you send the input directly to the server, calculate the same velocities and positions there and send this as ground truth down to the client. Clients only send inputs to server and the server dictates the result, allowing clients to lerp between corrections. This "eliminates" a big attack vector for cheater.

Answer (score 4):

Creator of FishNet here. The only possible way you can update a transforms data quicker than the built-in NetworkTransform is by sending a RPC and snapping the transform every time data arrives.

Otherwise setting the interpolation and interval to 1 on NetworkTransform will send every tick, and smooth over only 1 tick. It's literally the fastest possible way to update transforms without snapping them.

If you want the entire network to move faster then add a TimeManager component to your network manager and increase the tick rate.